# Observe/Detect Change in Ember Component {{yield}} Block

Tags: ember.js, jquery-isotope

Is there any way for a component to listen to, or observe, changes in yielded content?

I have a component which serves as an [isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) wrapper, and would like to be able to call some necessary clean-up isotope methods (such as .isotope('layout')) in case wrapped content changes (e.g. through filtering).

I've been able to do something similar with a View by observing controller properties, but would like to keep things less coupled if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know exactly what it is you want to do nor have I used isotope.js. But here's what I can tell you. The `{{yield}}` helper calls this function:

```
_yield: function(context, options, morph, blockArguments) {
        var view = options.data.view;
        var parentView = this._parentView;
        var template = get(this, 'template');

        if (template) {
            Ember.assert("A Component must have a parent view in order to yield.", parentView);

            view.appendChild(Ember.View, {
                isVirtual: true,
                tagName: '',
                template: template,
                _blockArguments: blockArguments,
                _contextView: parentView,
                _morph: morph,
                context: get(parentView, 'context'),
                controller: get(parentView, 'controller')
                //expose parent to children components?
            });
        }
}
```

Which means in theory you could expose a handle to your child components to set properties on the parent component. This clearly couples the two components. You can also make both the children and the parent take the "wrapped content" as attributes so that you can observe and manipulate in both places. I have used both approaches to great success. Which I used is dictated by context